# WPF Drag drop Create a Layout for Locations

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, devexpress, draggable

I have been troubling with wpf drag drop idea. So far now, I tried the list of examples below but it doesn't help me in here.

https://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/wpf-itemscontrol-drag-drop-behavior/

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/tree/master/samples/snippets/csharp/VS_Snippets_Wpf/DragDropWalkthrough/CS

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17266/Drag-and-Drop-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView

http://www.dotnetlead.com/ --> it's the answer but the technology seems old.

**My question in here** ; User can arrange the location and items included in that location by drag and dropping the object or whatever. What actualy I want to do in this image you can see here : [image: wpf drag drop example image] . image2:https://ibb.co/jhip2c, user will drag the object from the list of objects(*left side in the image* ) to right side (usercontrol,wrap Panel etc.). For this also I'm available to use DevExpress tools.

Solution I tried as also treeList but it is not the request from my instructor.

I'm also looking forward for any examples.So, please leave as a comment.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to DevExpress controls, I recommend using their `LayoutControl`.  It supports [grouping, tabs, and handles label positioning for you](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/8147/Controls-and-Libraries/Layout-Management/Tile-and-Layout/Layout-and-Data-Layout-Controls/Layout-Control).  It also allows users to enter a [customization mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/8154/Controls-and-Libraries/Layout-Management/Tile-and-Layout/Layout-and-Data-Layout-Controls/Customization-Mode) wherein they can add, remove, and rearrange items using drag-and-drop.  Based on the mock-up you provided, this is probably what your instructor wants you to do, because the mechanics appear identical:

[image: Screenshot]

From DevExpress's help library, below is an [example](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/8360/Controls-and-Libraries/Layout-Management/Tile-and-Layout/Examples/How-to-Build-Non-Linear-Layout-via-LayoutControl) of using this system to create a non-trivial layout with standalone fields, groups, and tabs:

```xml
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
        Height="300"
        Width="572">
  <Grid>
    <lc:LayoutControl Orientation="Vertical">
      <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal">
        <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">
          <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal" View="GroupBox" Header="Group 1" IsCollapsible="True">
            <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 1:" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
              <TextBox/>
            </lc:LayoutItem>
            <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical" lc:LayoutControl.AllowHorizontalSizing="True">
              <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 2:" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBox/>
              </lc:LayoutItem>
              <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 3:" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBox/>
              </lc:LayoutItem>
            </lc:LayoutGroup>
          </lc:LayoutGroup>
          <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 4:"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" lc:LayoutControl.AllowVerticalSizing="True">
            <TextBox/>
          </lc:LayoutItem>
        </lc:LayoutGroup>
        <lc:LayoutGroup View="Tabs" lc:LayoutControl.AllowHorizontalSizing="True">
          <lc:LayoutGroup Header="Tab 1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 5:">
              <TextBox/>
            </lc:LayoutItem>
            <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 6:" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
              <TextBox/>
            </lc:LayoutItem>
          </lc:LayoutGroup>
          <lc:LayoutGroup Header="Tab 2" Orientation="Vertical">
            <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 7:">
              <TextBox/>
            </lc:LayoutItem>
            <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 8:">
              <TextBox/>
            </lc:LayoutItem>
          </lc:LayoutGroup>
        </lc:LayoutGroup>
      </lc:LayoutGroup>
      <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal">
        <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 9:" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
          <TextBox Width="100"/>
        </lc:LayoutItem>
        <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 10:">
          <TextBox/>
        </lc:LayoutItem>
        <lc:LayoutItem Label="Item 11:" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <TextBox Width="100"/>
        </lc:LayoutItem>
      </lc:LayoutGroup>
    </lc:LayoutControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The results look like this:

[image: Screenshot of Example Results]